# bash bash xargs ssh bash sourcing failed on remote node

Tags: ssh, parallel-processing, xargs

I am trying to run following

```
export SSH_KEY_PATH=./id_rsa
cat t | grep admin | awk -F"=" '{print $2}' | nl | xargs -I{} -n 2  -P30  bash -c 'ssh  -i ${SSH_KEY_PATH} -o "StrictHostKeyChecking no"  opc@$1 "sudo su - maverick bash -c \" sleep 2;source  /u01/data/b.conf.properties; echo ${NAME} \" "'
```

i am able to run invidual command like `\"hostname;id\"` instead of `\" sleep 2;source  /u01/data/b.conf.properties; echo ${NAME} \"`

I need to source this b.conf.properies file so i can use variables inside further in remote shell. please HELP I need to run following

```
export SSH_KEY_PATH=./id_rsa
cat t | grep admin | awk -F"=" '{print $2}' | nl | xargs -I{} -n 2  -P30  bash -c 'ssh  -i ${SSH_KEY_PATH} -o "StrictHostKeyChecking no"  opc@$1 "sudo su - maverick bash -c \" sleep 2;source  /u01/data/b.conf.properties; bash -x ${INST_BIN}/doCrossOver.sh \" "'
```

Comment: That's a loooong one liner.  Consider breaking it up, especially since you're sudo-ing in the middle.

Comment: You wrote _i am able to run invidual command like \"hostname;id\" instead of \"…\"_. That is not plausible, since it is part of the command `su - maverick bash -c \"…\"`. The synopsis of `su` is `su [options] [username]`, so `su` does not honor the extra arguments `bash -c \"…\"`, whatever there may be.